# Difference between pointer and reference as thread parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, reference, stdthread

This is the example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

void f1(double& ret) {
   ret=5.;
}

void f2(double* ret) {
   *ret=5.;
}

int main() {
   double ret=0.;
   thread t1(f1, ret);
   t1.join();
   cout << "ret=" << ret << endl;
   thread t2(f2, &ret);
   t2.join();
   cout << "ret=" << ret << endl;   
}
```

And the output is:

```
ret=0
ret=5
```

Compiled with gcc 4.5.2, with and without `-O2` flag.

Is this expected behavior?

Is this program data race free?

Thank you

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The constructor of `std::thread` deduces argument types and stores copies of them by value. This is needed to ensure the lifetime of the argument object is at least the same as that of the thread.

C++ template function argument type deduction mechanism deduces type `T` from an argument of type `T&`. All arguments to `std::thread` are copied and then passed to the thread function so that  `f1()` and `f2()` always use that copy.

If you insist on using a reference, wrap the argument using `boost::ref()` or `std::ref()`:

```
thread t1(f1, boost::ref(ret));
```

Or, if you prefer simplicity, pass a pointer. This is what `boost::ref()` or `std::ref()` do for you behind the scene.

Comment: This really helped me, thanks +1. If this message will still be noticed by anyone, may I ask the reason `thread` uses this mechanism. Has this something to do with c, or does it have a completely different reason?

Comment: @patrik Value semantics (copying) are safe compared to storing a reference or a pointer. Reference or a pointer may become dangling when the object they refer to gets destroyed. This is why `std::bind` and `std::thread` store arguments by value by default and you have to explicitly ask it to do a less safe thing.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to pass parameters by reference to a `std::thread` you must enclose each of them in `std::ref`:

```
thread t1(f1, std::ref(ret));
```

More info [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-3.html).

Answer (score 9):

That you are required an explicit `std::ref()` (or `boost::ref()`) in these situations is actually a very useful safety feature as passing a reference can be by nature a dangerous thing to do.

With a non-const reference there is quite often a danger that you are passing in a local variable, with a const-reference it might be a temporary, and as you are creating a function to be called in a different thread (and with bind in general, often a function to be called later / in an asynchronous way) you will have the big danger of the object being no longer valid.

binding looks tidy but these bugs are the hardest to find, as where the error is caught (i.e. in calling the function) is not the same place that the error was made (at the time of binding) and it can be very hard to work out exactly which function is being called at the time, and therefore where it was bound.

It is safe in your instance as you join the thread in the scope of the variable you are passing as reference. Therefore when you know that to be the case there is a mechanism for passing a reference.

It is not a feature of the language I would like to see changed, particularly as there is probably a lot of existing code relying on it making a copy that would break if it just took by reference automatically (and would then need an explicit way to force a copy).