# Synchronization after thread end

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition

Because part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116756/difference-between-pointer-and-reference-as-thread-parameter) question wasn't addressed, I'm making it a separate question:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

void f2(double* ret) {
   *ret=5.;
}

int main() {
   double ret=0.;
   thread t2(f2, &ret);
   t2.join();
   cout << "ret=" << ret << endl;   
}
```

Is this program data race free?
Are there any guarantees, with respect to new C++ memory model, that accesses to variable `ret` from thread `t2` and thread `main` are synchronized?

I mean, it is obvious that accesses from `t2` and `main` won't collide if the program is executed on the same core.
But what if `t2` and `main` are executed on different cores?
Are there any guarantees that core's caches will synchronize before `main` continues execution?

I'd appreciate if somebody could provide same references.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no implicit synchronization here.  `join` is explicit synchronization between threads.

Comment: ok, I changed the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is data race free.  [thread.thread.member]/p5 describes join() with a *Synchronization* paragraph:

Synchronization: The completion of the thread represented by *this synchronizes
with (1.10) the corresponding successful join() return. [Note: Operations on *this are not synchronized. —endnote]

(1.10) refers to [intro.multithread] which is a section too long to quote but defines in excruciating detail the phrase "synchronizes with".

The latest working draft is [N3225](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf).