# Why does passing object reference arguments to thread function fails to compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I've come to a problem using the new c++11 `std::thread` interface.
I can't figure out how to pass a reference to a `std::ostream` to the function that the thread will execute.

Here's an example with passing an integer(compile and work as expected under gcc 4.6) :

```
void foo(int &i) {
    /** do something with i **/
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int k = 10;
std::thread t(foo, k);
```

But when I try passing an ostream it does not compile :

```
void foo(std::ostream &os) {
    /** do something with os **/
    os << "This should be printed to os" << std::endl;
}

std::thread t(foo, std::cout);
```

Is there a way to do just that, or is it not possible at all ??

NB: from the compile error it seems to come from a deleted constructor...

Comment: For primitives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116756/difference-between-pointer-and-reference-as-thread-parameter

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Threads **copy** their arguments (think about it, that's The Right Thing). If you want a reference explicitly, you have to wrap it with `std::ref` (or `std::cref` for constant references):

```
std::thread t(foo, std::ref(std::cout));
```

(The reference wrapper is a wrapper with value semantics around a reference. That is, you can *copy* the wrapper, and all copies will contain the same reference.)

As usual, this code is only correct as long as the object to which you refer remains alive. Caveat emptor.

Comment: @JohnDibling: If you're a masochist and believe that there's too much plusplus in your C, yes.

Comment: I do have masochistic tendancies, I guess.

Comment: @JohnDibling: No. Passing a pointer does not give you a reference.

Comment: @Tomalak: Nor did I say or imply that it did.

Comment: Passing a pointer would require a change in the program logic, I think we can all agree on that.

Comment: For the record, I do not recommend passing by pointer in the general case.  The only reason I mentioned it in a comment was for completeness.  Not that it matters much, but I did up vote before I commented.

Comment: Ah thanks, I forgot about thread argument being passed by value. But what about the `int` case?

Comment: @BenjaminA.: What about it? It's passed by value, too.