# std::thread pass by reference calls copy constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, copy-constructor, stdthread

Well I have an issue with passing data into a thread using std::thread. I thought I understood the general semantics of copy constructors, etc. but it seems I don't quite grasp the problem.  I have a simple class called Log that has hidden it's copy constructor thusly:

```
class Log
{
public:
    Log(const char filename[], const bool outputToConsole = false);
    virtual ~Log(void);

    //modify behavior
    void appendStream(std::ostream *);
    //commit a new message
    void commitStatus(const std::string str);

private:
    //members
    std::ofstream fileStream;
    std::list<std::ostream *> listOfStreams;

    //disable copy constructor and assignment operator
    Log(const Log &);
    Log & operator=(const Log &);
}
```

now I have a main based heavily on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp

```
int main()
{
    static int portNumber = 10000;

    Log logger("ServerLog.txt", true);
    logger.commitStatus("Log Test String");

    try {
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        server(ioService, portNumber, logger);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
        logger.commitStatus(e.what());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see that main calls the function server and passes the IOService, portNumber and logger. The logger is passed by reference, thusly:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void server(boost::asio::io_service &ioService, unsigned int port, Log &logger)
{
    logger.commitStatus("Server Start");

    tcp::acceptor acc(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

    while(true)
    {
        tcp::socket sock(ioService);
        acc.accept(sock);

        std::thread newThread(session, &sock, logger);
        newThread.detach();
    }

    logger.commitStatus("Server closed");
}
```

I get a compiler error when I try to pass the logger (or the socket) to the thread by reference, but I do not get the error when passing it to the session() by reference

```
static void session(tcp::socket *sock, Log &logger)
{
    std::cout << " session () " << std::endl;
}
```

Now I thought that I understood correctly that a reference is the same as passing a pointer. That is, it does not call the copy constructor, it simply passes the pointer, which it lets you syntactically treat like it's not a pointer.

> error C2248: 'Log::Log' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Log'
>
> 1>          \log.h(55) : see declaration of 'Log::Log'
>
> 1>          \log.h(28) : see declaration of 'Log'
>
> ...
>
> : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread(_Fn,_V0_t &&,_V1_t)' being compiled
>
> 1>          with
>
> 1>          [
>
> 1>              *Fn=void (*_cdecl *)(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *,Log &),
>
> 1>              _V0_t=boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *,
>
> 1>              _V1_t=Log &
>
> 1>          ]

However if I modify it to pass a pointer, everything is happy

```
...
        std::thread newThread(session, &sock, &logger);
...

static void session(tcp::socket *sock, Log *logger)
{
    std::cout << " session () " << std::endl;
}
```

**Why is passing by reference calling my copy constructor**. Is there something special happening here because of std::thread? Did I misunderstand the copy constructor and pass by reference?

I get a different but equally baffling error if I try to use std::move() as it is done in the example. Is it possible my VS2012 is not implementing C++11 correctly?

Comment: Where did you get information that it's passed by reference?

Comment: @zoska: He's clearly thinking of `session` taking it by reference, forgetting entirely about the intermediate call(s).

Comment: Since this question is marked C++11: You could/should hide the copy constructor and assignment operator using the delete keyword.

Comment: @Ligtness, yes I was completely forgetting about the intermediate calls. Stupid mistake I guess

Comment: @Kit, I tried to disable the copy constructor and assignment operator using the delete keyword, and for some reason it complained. Something about, 'unexpected token before ;' I can't remember exactly what the error message was. I'm guessing VS2012 doesn't support all C++11 features yet.

Comment: @user1196033: You are right. You need VS2013 for that feature (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299545/passing-arguments-to-thread-function

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`std::thread` takes its arguments by value. You can get reference semantics back by using `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::thread newThread(session, &sock, std::ref(logger));
```

Obviously you must make sure that `logger` outlives the thread.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you. I did not know about std::ref().

Comment: To be explicit, although the session function takes Log by reference, the std::thread's constructor takes Log by value.

Answer (score 6):

> I get a compiler error when I try to pass the logger (or the socket) to the thread by reference

It is not sufficient for the thread's entrypoint function to take a reference type: the thread object *itself* takes its arguments by value. This is because you usually want a copy of objects in a separate thread.

To get around this, you may pass `std::ref(logger)`, which is a [*reference wrapper*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) hiding reference semantics under a copyable object.