# What is a valid way to stop a std::thread by an external signal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This is a code which works not as designed please explain me what is wrong here (code simplified to make this more readable).

```
shm_server server;

std::thread s{server};

// some work...

std::cout << "press any key to stop the server";
_getch();
server.stop();
s.join();
```

It looks like I call a `stop` method for another copy of `shm_server` class.
because `stop()` only sets `std::atomic_bool done;` (`shm_server` member) to `true` but I see that thread function (this is `operator()` of `shm_server`) still sees `done` equal to `false`.

`std::thread` has only move contructor?

How to send a signal to server correctly in this typical case?

```
class shm_server {
    std::atomic_bool    done;
public:
    shm_server() : done{false} {}
    shm_server(shm_server& ) : done{false} {}
    void operator()() {
       while (!done) {
       //...
       }
    }
    void stop() {
       done = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Try `std::thread s{std::ref(server)};` to avoid the copying

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21048906/103167

Comment: thank you! std::ref solution works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have somehow shot yourself into the foot by making `shm_server` copyable. I believe you did this in order to get rid of the compiler error, not because copy semantics on that class are particularly useful. I'd recommend you delete that constructor again. If you really want copy semantics, have the constructor take its argument by reference to `const`.

```
class shm_server  // cannot copy or move
{

  std::atomic_bool done_ {};

public:

  void
  operator()()
  {
    this->run();
  }

  void
  run()
  {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while (!this->done_.load())
      {
        std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " working..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
      }
  }

  void
  stop()
  {
    this->done_.store(true);
  }

};
```

I have factored out the logic of the call operator into a named function for convenience. You don't need to do that but I'll use it later in the example.

Now we somehow have to make the `run` member function be executed on its own thread. If you write

```
shm_server server {};
std::thread worker {server};  // won't compile
```

the compiler won't let you do it as it – as you have conjectured yourself – would attempt to copy the `server` object which isn't copyable.

[@Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665619/what-is-a-valid-way-to-stop-stdthread-by-external-signal#comment-57077312) to wrap the `server` object into a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) which is an object that behaves like a reference.

```
shm_server server {};
std::thread worker {std::ref(server)};
```

This works as intended and effectively passes a pointer to the `std::thread` constructor, rather than the actual `server` object.

However, I find that this is not the most straight-forward solution here. What you really want to do is run a member function of your `server` on a different thread. And `std::thread`'s constructor lets you do just that.

```
shm_server server {};
std::thread worker {&shm_server::run, &server};
```

Here, I'm passing the address of the `run` member function and a pointer to the `server` object (that will be passed as the implicit `this` pointer) as argument. I have introduced the `run` function since the syntax might be less irritating. You can also pass the address of the call operator directly.

```
shm_server server {};
std::thread worker {&shm_server::operator(), &server};
```

Here is a complete example.

```
int
main()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " starting up" << std::endl;
  shm_server server {};
  std::thread worker {&shm_server::operator(), &server};
  //std::thread worker {std::ref(server)};                 // same effect
  //std::thread worker {&shm_server::run, &server};        // same effect
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
  server.stop();
  worker.join();
  std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " good bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
140435324311360 starting up
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435306977024 working...
140435324311360 good bye
```

If you believe that a `shm_server` will only ever be useful if run on its own thread, you can also give it a `std::thread` as data member and have its constructor (or a dedicated `start` member function, if you prefer) start and its destructor join the thread.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class shm_server
{

  std::atomic_bool done_ {};
  std::thread worker_ {};

public:

  shm_server()
  {
    this->worker_ = std::thread {&shm_server::run_, this};
  }

  ~shm_server()
  {
    this->done_.store(true);
    if (this->worker_.joinable())
      this->worker_.join();
  }

private:

  void
  run_()
  {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while (!this->done_.load())
      {
        std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " working..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
      }
  }

};


int
main()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " starting up" << std::endl;
  {
    shm_server server {};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
  }
  std::clog << std::this_thread::get_id() << " good bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. yes, I've added copy ctor without real analyzing the problem inside , just saw the problem with a copy atomic_bool. and after advice with std::ref, I've removed this as unused.. regarding member passing. I used an object itself not for some reason just it looks clear than function passing, so really , member passing is ok for the functionality. and question about thread object inside the server: is this pattern more preferable? any advanteges?

Comment: Encapsulating the threading logic inside your server class frees your clients from having to worry about it. On the other hand, it makes the design less flexible. Maybe some clients want to run it on their own thread or use another threading library. Also think about unit-testability. I don't know what will fit your use-case well.

Comment: thank you,encapsulating is preferable for me, client wants to "create and forget" about server object. ideally, server should manage all completely by itself