# Start std::thread in member function of object that does not have a copy constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I want to start a `std::thread` at a member function of an object that does not have a copy constructor. The standard way of starting a thread at a member function (see for example [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)) needs a copy constructor. I thought I could get around this by using `std::ref` (see for example [std::thread pass by reference calls copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048906/stdthread-pass-by-reference-calls-copy-constructor)), but no luck.

Here is my code. Thread `t1` works, but not `t2`. If I try to uncomment the two lines, it gives:

```
error: attempt to use a deleted function 
__invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...); ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:357:5: note: 
in instantiation of function template specialization
'std::__1::__thread_execute<void (Dummy::*)(), std::__1::reference_wrapper<Dummy> , 1>' 
requested here __thread_execute(*__p, _Index()); ^ 
etc.
```

How do I start the thread directly at `print()`, without needing `uselessFunction`?

Also, I'd like to understand the error better. Which "deleted function" is the compiler complaining about?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Dummy {
public:
    std::atomic<bool> flag;  // atomic kills implicitly created copy constructor
    void print() { std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl; }
};

void uselessFunction(Dummy &d) {
    d.print();
}

int main() {
    Dummy d{};
    std::thread t1(uselessFunction, std::ref(d));  // this works
    // std::thread t2(&Dummy::print, std::ref(d)); // does not work
    t1.join();
    // t2.join();
}
```

Comment: What if you pass a pointer? `Also, I'd like to understand the error better... which "deleted function" is the compiler complaining about?` Probably the copy constructor, the error message should tell you which function.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I cannot get an error for `t2`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kCZrnpBMKPAK0enX

Comment: I am using clang. The error looks like this, which I don't quite understand: `error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:357:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_execute<void (Dummy::*)(), std::__1::reference_wrapper<Dummy> , 1>' requested here
    __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
    ^` etc.

Comment: @MartinCook Which version of clang?

Comment: @NathanOliver `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`

Comment: @NathanOliver and it should be c++11

Comment: @MartinCook OK.  I was able to [reproduce this error with clang 3.8.1 or lower](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YMINeS8P5stKCFUj).  I went back to gcc's 4.8.2 and it compiled without issue.  I'm suspecting this may have been a clang bug that has since been fixed.  The workaround in my answer should work for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I can confirm that this is compiler version issue. It compiled fine when I used g++ `g++-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.1.0) 8.1.0`. Btw, thanks for showing me wandbox, that is a great site.

Comment: @MartinCook It is great for trying to find out if something is a compiler bug.  Or just what version you would need to update to to support some code you want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to call the function.  `std::invoke` is smart enough to be able to take a pointer to an object and call a member function with it.  That means you can change `t2` to

```
std::thread t2(&Dummy::print, &d);
```

and get the correct behavior.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend! That works nicely. Do you know what the "deleted function" is?

Comment: @MartinCook I'm not able to reproduce your error.  What compiler and which standard are you using to compile?