# No matching function to invoke, using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm new to `std::thread`s and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The idea is having a static function inside a `DataUtils` class that splits the program in 10 threads, every of which will calculate "a part" of a convolution between two `vectors`.

For some reason it seems that the compiler can't assign the right function to the thread, but the arguments are correct.

Here is my code (I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this...)

```
void threadconv (std::vector<double> const &f, std::vector<double> const &g, std::vector<double> &out, int start, int stop,int nf,int ng){

   
    for(auto i(start); i < stop; ++i) {
        int const jmn = (i >= ng - 1)? i - (ng - 1) : 0;
        int const jmx = (i <  nf - 1)? i            : nf - 1;
        for(auto j(jmn); j <= jmx; ++j) {
            out[i] += (f[j] * g[i - j]);
        }
    }
}

class DataUtils{
static std::vector<double> multiThreadedConvolution(std::vector<double> const &f, std::vector<double> const &g, int divide){
        int const nf = f.size();
        int const ng = g.size();
        int const n  = nf + ng - 1;
        int i=0;

        std::vector<double> out(n, double());

        std::thread t1 (threadconv,f,g,out,0,divide,nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t2 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide,nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t3 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide,nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t4 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t5 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t6 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t7 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t8 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t9 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,(divide*i)+divide, nf,ng);i++;
        std::thread t10 (threadconv,f,g,out,divide*i,out.size(), nf,ng);

        t1.join();
         t2.join();
         t3.join();
         t4.join();
         t5.join();
         t6.join();
         t7.join();
         t8.join();
         t9.join();
         t10.join();
        return out;
    }

}
```

After trying to compile, this is the error message I receive:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int, int, int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int, int> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int, int, int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int, int> >::_Indices)’
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:231:4: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype (std::__invoke((_S_declval<_Ind>)()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<_Tuple>::_M_invoke(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind ...>) [with long unsigned int ..._Ind = {_Ind ...}; _Tuple = std::tuple<void (*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int, int, int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int, int>]
    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:231:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/thread: In substitution of ‘template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype (std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int, int, int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int, int> >::_M_invoke<_Ind ...>(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind1 ...>) [with long unsigned int ..._Ind = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:240:2:   required from ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int, int, int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int, int> >’
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:127:22:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, int, int, int, int); _Args = {const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, int&, const int&, const int&}]’
```

Comment: `std::ref(out)`

Comment: Could you please clarify where this has to be put, and why? thanks

Comment: `std::thread` constructor makes a copy of every parameter you pass it.  `std::reference_wrapper<T>` can be copied and still converts to a reference to the same original object.  Otherwise `invoke` tries to pass the copied object to `threadconv` and can't bind the non-const reference to the temporary copy.

Comment: @NateEldredge I haven't looked too thoroughly but it looks like each thread writes to its own range in the vector. That's safe.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I first thought that too, but each thread writes to a mutually-exclusive subrange so there's no problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::thread pass by reference calls copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048906/stdthread-pass-by-reference-calls-copy-constructor)