# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

I'm facing a threads problem:

Here is a code to reproduce the error:

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "mychrono.hpp"

int main()

{
    
    std::vector<Chronometer*> car_crono;
    Chronometer chrono, output_chrono;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;


    while (1) {
       

        
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            car_crono.push_back(new Chronometer);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
            {
        
                    threads.push_back(std::thread(&Chronometer::start_chrono, car_crono[i], std::ref(chrono)));                     
            
             }

        //std::cout << "Threads size: " << threads.size();
        for (auto &th : threads) {
                    th.join();
                    }
            
       std::cout << "Hello-world" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My chrono.cpp

```
#include "mychrono.hpp"

#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sstream>
#include <thread>


//int Chronometer::hour(0), min(0), sec(0);

Chronometer::Chronometer() : hour(0), min(0), sec(0)
{

}

Chronometer& Chronometer::start_chrono(Chronometer& chrono)
{
 
  if(chrono.hour == 0 && chrono.min == 0 && chrono.sec == 0)
  {
    bool condition = true;
    while(condition) {
      sleep(1);
      chrono.sec++;

      if(sec > 59) {
        chrono.min++;
        chrono.sec = 0;

      }

      if(min > 59) {
        chrono.hour++;
        chrono.sec = 0;
        chrono.min = 0;
      }
      if(chrono.sec == 10)
      {
        condition = false;
      }

      std::cout << "chrono: " << chrono << std::endl;

   }

  }  

  return chrono;
}
```

My chrono.hpp

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#ifndef mychrono_hpp
#define mychrono_hpp

class Chronometer
{
    private:
        int hour, min, sec;
        //std::stringstream ss;
        //Chronometer chrono;

    public:

        Chronometer();
        Chronometer& start_chrono(Chronometer& chrono);
        Chronometer& finish_chrono(Chronometer& chrono);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& flux, Chronometer t);
        Chronometer& operator=(const Chronometer& other);
        ~Chronometer();

};


#endif
```

My purpose is just to launch independant several chronometers in background to get the result. For one instantiated Chronometer object the program crash at the end with the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
Abandon (core dumped)
```

But for 2 chronometers for example, the treads increment one chronometer 2 times faster instead of increment two independent chronometer.

I'm a beginner in threads so I have no idea why is running like that

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I add easier code example below to reproduce the error and better explain the issue I'm facing of.

Comment: you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68909406/edit) that into your question rather than posting it as an answer

Comment: note that [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) before including standard library headers is likely to lead to bugs/crashes/weird compilation errors

Comment: your new code works for me (once I'd fixed the linker errors due to missing function implementations), please show a [mre]

Comment: It's not working for me if I'm not clearing the threads vector after execution. Moreover if I print simple message as edited in my code above like "hello-world" outside the thread. Why the message is not printed in the same time as the thread should run in background ?

Comment: `"Hello World"` won't print as `th.join()` will block until the thread completes. Is this exactly the code you are running? It didn't link for me due to missing function implementations

Comment: Yes it's running sorry but it's not the result I was expecting for.  Moroever, I need the thread to use as a background which is not the case in my code. I thought the thread could do that

Comment: How it's possible to run in background ?

Comment: just don't call `join` until you actually want to join the threads

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

1. in your `while` loop in `main` after calling `join` you leave the threads in the `threads` vector, on the next iteration of the loop you will again call `join` on the same threads, `join` throws [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) if you call `join` more than once. Call `clear` on`threads` after joining the threads.
2. Inside `start_chrono` you have multiple threads modifying `chrono.sec` with no synchronisation, this leads to a race condition where not all threads will satisfy the `chrono.sec == 10` condition leading them to continue executing forever as the condition `if (sec > 59)` which should presumably be `if (chrono.sec > 59)` is never true as `sec` doesn't change.
3. As you are calling `join` after creating the threads `main` will be blocked and can't perform any other work. You should only call `join` when you actually want to wait for the thread to stop executing.