# Calling a std::thread constructor with a class member function that takes parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I know there exists [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299545/passing-arguments-to-thread-function) one as well. 
I have gone through both of them and haven't been able to solve my problem. I was able to run examples for class member functions that take zero arguments, but was not able to deduce what the constructor for the thread would look like in case the member function had arguments.

I have a class A. A has a member function f that takes 2 parameters p1 and p2. 
I have instantiated an object a of class A. I want to call the function f in a thread.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) :

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

is how I must write the constructor.

I am having trouble deciphering the above definition. How can I call a.f(p1,p2) defined as

`void A::f(int p1, int p2)`

in a thread ?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the definition `template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`. may be then I can think how a lambda can be used to do it.

Comment: Roughly, `thread ([&a] (q1, q2) { a.f (q1, q2); }, p1, p2);`

Comment: `Function` stands for a function object, that you can create in various ways, a lambda object is a good way to do it.

Comment: @T.C. Does `&A::f, a` together define the function object ?

Comment: @T.C. The difference is that your version makes a copy of `a`.

Comment: @T.C. That did't work. I don't know why. Got this error : `/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Stream::*)(bool)>(std::reference_wrapper<Stream>, int)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
`

Comment: @Wildling Yeah, I just tested that, `reference_wrapper` don't work as the `this` argument if you pass a pointer-to-member. To pass by ref, use `std::thread t(&A::f, &a, p1, p2);`. To pass by value, use `std::thread t(&A::f, a, p1, p2);`

Comment: @Wildling No, that is a special case.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, that works. Can you please explain how. I mean the function definition of the `std::thread` mentions only two parameters - the function object and the parameters to the function to be run. But we are passing 3 - the function object, the object and the parameters. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @user1095108 Can you please tell me what such special cases are called; so that I might look them up ?

Comment: @Wildling Member functions have an implicit first parameter for `this`. The `std::thread` constructor maps the second parameter to that.

Comment: @Wildling If you read the cppreference page you link to, it describes exactly how the function is called in various cases. The applicable case here is the paragraph starting with "If f is pointer to a member function of class T".

Comment: Another solution:

    int p1, p2; // assuming you have integer args
    A obj;
    std::function<void (int, int)> func = std::bind(&A::f, p1, p2);
    std::thread thd{func};

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply pass the arguments:

```
std::thread t(&A::f, &bar, p1, p2);
t.join();
```

**Note**: Notice that we are passing the address of your `bar` object, otherwise the thread constructor would copy your object. By doing this you have to guarantee that your object outlives your thread. Note, that the same is true for the other arguments. In case of the arguments you can simply use `std::ref`.

In general, as mentioned in my other post, the `std::thread` constructor is defined in terms of the `INVOKE` definition (**§20.8.2.1**):

> Define INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN) as follows:
>
> - (t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN) when f is a pointer to a member function of a class T and t1 is an object of type T or a reference to an object of
>     type T or a reference to an object of a type derived from T;
> - ((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN) when f is a pointer to a member function of a class T and t1 is not one of the types described in the previous
>     item;
> - t1.*f when N ==    1 and f is a pointer to member data of a class T and  t  1 is an object of type T or a
>     reference to an object of type T or a reference to an object of a
>     type derived from T;
> - (*t1).*f when N == 1 and f is a pointer to member data of a class T and t 1 is not one of the types described in the previous item;
> - f(t1, t2, ..., tN) in all other cases.

Comment: OP wants the equivalent of `a.f(p1, p2);`, if they just use your solution as is they won't get that.

Comment: @juanchopanza you mean because of the copying of bar? Or what are you referring to? I understood the question to be about the parameters part.

Comment: I just mean the copying. Better to clarify that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Interesting, but I am just passing the arguments by `std::ref` and not the object.

Comment: I just realised I misread part of your edit. That looks OK. Sorry about the noise.