# Why does passing the `function with call by reference` into std::thread cause compile failure for int but fine for user-defined class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++11

I know if I want to apply *call by reference* via `std::thread`, I should wrap passing argument with `std::ref` as `std::reference_wrapper` to be copy-able. I met a compile failure when I try to directly pass a *named `int` variable* with function accepting `int&`. This is nice and gives a hint I should wrap it with `std::ref`.

```
auto f = [](int&) {};
int obj;
std::thread t(f, obj);            // compile failure                               
std::thread t2(f, std::ref(obj)); // ok
```

Error message on Visual Studio 2015: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DEiR1jF1)

But in the case with **user-defined object**, it looks like no such compile error to give the hint. Of course the `call by reference` does not work, the passed value is not affected after thread completed.

```
struct MyObject { int i; MyObject(): i(0){} };

auto f = [](MyObject& obj) { obj.i = 100 };
MyObject obj;
std::thread t(f, obj); // compile fine
// obj.i is still 0
```

Why does compiler allow to compile if type is not built-in type for this wrong usage?

### Updated:

I am using MS Visual Studio 2015. This issue does not happen on gcc.

Thanks to chris and T.C. After disabled the visaul studio language extension, both user-defined object and built-in types are not allowed to compile.

It looks like caused by a MS extension.

Comment: [Doesn't work with Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e99d8323e4497fc). Try it with language extensions disabled on VS and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Typical behavior with the MSVC extension allowing a non-const lvalue reference to bind to an rvalue (though apparently only for non-built-in types).

Comment: Yeah, I try it on Wandbox with gcc, User-defined object also caused compile error.  I am going to try to disable VS extension.

Comment: @chris  After disabled Visual Studio, the user-defined object case is also compile error. Thanks. I have not thought it is a VS specific thing.

Comment: You shouldn't have to disable extensions (sometimes that's not an option because things like `Windows.h` fail to compile without them); setting the warning level to `/W4` should cause warnings about binding an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: Yes. I am just working on a compile error issue because one of my library includes <windows.h> to use win32 API. It looks not so easy to ensure not touch that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does passing object reference arguments to thread function fails to compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299545/why-does-passing-object-reference-arguments-to-thread-function-fails-to-compile)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn it's cool that question's situation is opposed to mine. He is fine in int& but failed in non-builtin type.

Comment: @ChenOT Although wondering about why MSVC causes this behaviour with language extension is fair enough, passing by reference to a thread function should always involve reference wrappers (eg `std::ref` or `std::cref`). With wrappers, both of your examples should compile fine. So I think this question is not really a programming one, and therefore doesn't really belong on SO. It should simply be a bug report to MSVC, don't you think?