# Thread pool in C++ not using references from args

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I am trying to get a thread pool to run a method were the arguments are passed by reference. The
method I want to run is:

`void Foo(const std::vector<std::string> &arg1, std::vector<int> &arg2, int size) {//modify elements of arg2}`

I am submitting this function to a thread pool:

```
Pool.submit(Foo, arg1,arg2,size);
...

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        //Create a callable std::function with parameters that will be executed by a free std::thread

        std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        //Place the callable std::function into a shared_ptr

        auto pTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>> (func);

        //Wrap packaged task into void std::function using a lambda std::function

        std::function<void()> pWrappedTask = [pTask]() {(*pTask)();};

        //Increment this for job status tracking
        JobsRequested++;
        //Enqueue generic wrapper std::function
        JobQ.enqueue(pWrappedTask);
        //Wake up one std::thread if its waiting
        PoolCondVar.notify_one();
    }
```

I found that the the arguments are not being passed by reference, so when the thread calls Foo, the original variable does not get modified. If I call the function without using the thread pool, the Foo works correctly. I think it has something to do with how I am setting up the function `std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);` because when I debug the function within each thread, the address of my arguments change between threads.
Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried to call `Pool.submit(Foo, std::ref(arg1), std::ref(arg2), size);`?

Comment: Almost duplicated question [Why does passing object reference arguments to thread function fails to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299545/why-does-passing-object-reference-arguments-to-thread-function-fails-to-compile).

Comment: Is jumping through all those hoops really necessary? `std::packaged_task` is all that's needed to put a task in a queue.

Comment: @DanielLangr This fixed the issue! If you submit this as an answer, I can vote for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`std::bind` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> The return type of `std::bind` holds a member object of type `std::decay<F>::type` constructed from `std::forward<F>(f)`, and one object per each of `args...`, of type `std::decay<Arg_i>::type`, similarly constructed from `std::forward<Arg_i>(arg_i)`.

Thanks to `decay`, the arguments are "stored-by-value", which means the arguments are either copy-constructed or move-constructed. This explains their different address.

As usually in such situations, the solution is in using [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
Pool.submit(Foo, std::ref(arg1), std::ref(arg2), size);
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4M3vK1cr9