# C++ reference wrapper as function argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference-wrapper

From my understanding, reference wrapper is just a wrapper on reference, nothing too special about it. But why it is treated as the reference itself (rather than the wrapper) inside the function when passed as a function argument?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void f(int& x){
    cout<<"f on int called"<<endl;
}

void f(reference_wrapper<int>& x){
    cout<<"f on wrapper called"<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int x = 10;
    f(ref(x)); // f on int called, why?

    reference_wrapper<int> z = ref(x);
    f(z); // f on wrapper called, this makes sense though
}
```

why does ref(x) treated as x itself inside function call? I come to this problem because I was trying to understand the use of ref() when [passing data among different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299545/why-does-passing-object-reference-arguments-to-thread-function-fails-to-compile). I think the ref() is necessary so any function argument with '&' need not be rewritten to avoid threads interfere with each other. But why the threads can treat ref(x) as x without using x.get()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> f(ref(x)); // f on int called, why?
> ```

Because [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) has a conversion operator to the stored reference; `ref(x)` returns an `std::reference_wrapper`, which could be converted to `int&` implicitly.

`void f(reference_wrapper<int>& x)` takes lvalue-reference to non-const, `std::ref` returns by-value, i.e. what it returns is an rvalue which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const. Then `f(ref(x));` calls the 1st overloaded `f` instead of the 2nd one. If you change it to `void f(reference_wrapper<int> x)` or `void f(const reference_wrapper<int>& x)` then it'll be called.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tICYHe3hTPPDIeLo)