# The value of the variable does not change outside thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am quite new to c++ and to threading, so this quesiton may be stupid. However, I have found preciously little information about my problem though I have searched for a solution for a long time. The problem is that I am unable to change the value of a variable outside its thread. The code snippet that I provide is shortened down to a reasonable size, but my issue should not have been affected.

I have done many different actions trying to slove the problem, but it still persists. The problem is that when I change the variables `from`, `is_input` and `dummy` inside `f` they are not changed in the main thread. I am not sure, but I doubt that it has something to do with other actions happen while the thread is Writing. It must be something that I miss here. I would be thankful for all input that helps solving the problem.

By the way, I am aware this may be something that I am meant to learn after getting a Little more used to the language, but many thing that is fun or motivating to program is possible after learning about threads.

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>

std::mutex m;

void f(std::string& from, bool& is_input, int& dummy){
    if (is_input == false){
        std::cout<<"From"<<"\n";
        std::cin>> from;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m);
        is_input = true;
        std::cout<<"is_input: "<<is_input<<" from "<<from<<std::endl;
        //lck.unlock(); //Should not be needed
    }
    ++dummy;
    std::cout<<"dummy: "<<dummy<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::string from = "";
    bool is_input = false;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    int counter = 0;
    int dummy = 1;
    std::thread th1(f,from, is_input, dummy);
    th1.join();
    while (1)
    {
    ++counter;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(4000));
    std::cout<<"the thread have slept now, prints is_input and     dummy\n"<<is_input<<"    "<<dummy<<std::endl;
        if (counter == 2){
            break;
         }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that should compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: VS 2012 default compiler, and by the way why do you Think that?

Comment: Ok, right when should I join?

Comment: The arguments of the function being references, and the thread constructor attempting to make copies of everything. G++ 4.8.2 and Clang 3.4 don't like it for sure.

Comment: Look up what join does. Also, there's no loop in your function. It's not going to be called repeatedly. It has to loop if you want it to run for a while.

Comment: Ok, so should I use pointers instead?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116756/difference-between-pointer-and-reference-as-thread-parameter

Comment: @ooga I know there is no loop, the first try was to actually get something to happen and then I wanted to keep it simple at first

Comment: @Vadim great, this was what I was looking for. It seems as it is a duplicate then, sorry for that.