# Threading to insert into a bimap

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-unordered

I would like to use multiple threads to insert into a `bimap`. I tried the following code:

**parallel_index.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_multiset_of.hpp>
#include "parallel_index.h"


namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::unordered_set_of<uint64_t>,
        bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<std::string> > bimap_reference;
typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
bimap_reference reference_index_vector;


size_t total_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

std::string sequence_content = "ABCDDBACDDDCBBAAACBDAADCBDAAADCBDADADACBDDCBBBCDCBCDAADCBBCDAAADCBDA";
uint64_t sequence_length = sequence_content.length();
int split = 5;
uint64_t erase_length = 0;
unsigned int seq_itr = 0;

std::mutex mtx;   // to protect against concurent access
int main(){
    thread_test::create_index index;
    std::thread threads[total_threads-1];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
        threads[i] = std::thread(&thread_test::create_index::reference_index_hash, std::ref(index), sequence_length, split, sequence_content, erase_length);
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
}



/*
 * Creating index
 */
void thread_test::create_index::reference_index_hash(uint64_t &sequence_length, int &split,
        std::string &sequence_content, uint64_t &erase_length  ){

    for (; seq_itr < sequence_length; ++seq_itr ){
        std::string splitstr = sequence_content.substr(erase_length, split);

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        reference_index_vector.insert(position(seq_itr, splitstr));
        seq_itr += split-1;
        erase_length += split;


// the length of test is very large so erase some text
        if(erase_length > 10000){ 
            sequence_content.erase(0,erase_length);
            erase_length = 0;
        }
    }


//  for( bimap_reference::const_iterator iter = reference_index_vector.begin(), iend = reference_index_vector.end();
//          iter != iend; ++iter ) {
//      std::cout << iter->left << " <--> "<< iter->right <<std::endl;
//  }

}
```

**parallel_index.h**

```
#ifndef PARALLEL_INDEX_H_
#define PARALLEL_INDEX_H_


#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_multiset_of.hpp>




//typedef boost::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, unsigned long int>& > reference_map;

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;

typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::unordered_set_of<uint64_t>,
        bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<std::string > > bimap_reference;
typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
extern bimap_reference reference_index_vector;


namespace thread_test{

class create_index{
public:
    void reference_index_hash(uint64_t &sequence_length, int &split,
            std::string &sequence_content, uint64_t &erase_length);
};
}


#endif /* PARALLEL_INDEX_H_ */
```

I use eclipse IDE to compile the code, but I get the errors

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I/home/ahussain/boost_1_65_1 -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"parallel_index.d" -MT"parallel_index.o" -o "parallel_index.o" "../parallel_index.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
                 from ../parallel_index.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_test::create_index::*)(long unsigned int&, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, long unsigned int&)>(std::reference_wrapper<thread_test::create_index>, long unsigned int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int)>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (thread_test::create_index::*)(long unsigned int&, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, long unsigned int&); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<thread_test::create_index>, long unsigned int&, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, long unsigned int&}]’
../parallel_index.cpp:42:149:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_test::create_index::*)(long unsigned int&, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, long unsigned int&)>(std::reference_wrapper<thread_test::create_index>, long unsigned int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_test::create_index::*)(long unsigned int&, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, long unsigned int&)>(std::reference_wrapper<thread_test::create_index>, long unsigned int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'parallel_index.o' failed
make: *** [parallel_index.o] Error 1
```

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950835/c-error-no-type-named-type-in-class-stdresult-ofvoid-stdunordered), but can't get away with the errors.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `create_index` instance that's going to be needed to provide `this` for `reference_index_hash`. I think you have more references involved than you've correctly passed or need. Need to take a closer look.

Comment: My mistake, the instance it there, but you want to pass it as a pointer, not as a reference.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `sequence_length, split, sequence_content, erase_length` in `std::ref` aswell? Or maybe taking a `const &` in the function signature could also work.

Comment: Just about right there, super.

Comment: @user4581301 Why pass by pointer?

Comment: @super I tried, but the result is not different.

Comment: @AwaitedOne because it will be used as `this` and `this` is a pointer.

Comment: @AwaitedOne I also tried it, and it works. [Live demo](https://ideone.com/x6mRiq).

Comment: As does changing the function signature to `void reference_index_hash(const uint64_t &sequence_length, const int &split, const std::string &sequence_content, const uint64_t &erase_length);`

Comment: @super And all should not be `const` because each thread is updating some variables.

Comment: @AwaitedOne I mostly point it out as an alternative. Might apply to someone who comes by later and reads this question. And to be fair, it's only `erase_length` that's being modified in your example so the others could be const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` can be passed as a simple pointer rather than a wrapped reference, but the remaining variables are expected to be references, so they need the `std::ref` treatment.

In other words

```
threads[i] = std::thread(&thread_test::create_index::reference_index_hash,
                         &index,
                         std::ref(sequence_length),
                         std::ref(split),
                         std::ref(sequence_content),
                         std::ref(erase_length));
```

will compile.

But...

Unfortunately this means you'll have multiple threads all working off the same variables. This is usually a non-starter because the threads will be concurrently accessing and wreaking havoc on the values stored by the variables. You will have to rethink how you want to use these variables and either pass them by value or find a better way to isolate or protect them.

And...

```
std::thread threads[total_threads-1];
```

combined with

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++)
```

will result in one too many `thread`s going into the array. 0 through `total_threads` is a count of `total_threads` `thread`s, not `total_threads-1`.

Comment: You can actually pass `index` as a pointer, in a reference wrapper and by value. All works.

Comment: That will compile, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. Note how all of the `this`es are different here: https://ideone.com/miXEqP. On rethought reference wrapper should work, but why bother? Just pass a pointer and save the overhead.

Comment: Yes, only usefull if you want the thread to operate on copies of the instance of course. Atleast pointers and `std::ref` gives same result.

Comment: Passing references usually gives more guarantees then pointers, so it can sometime lead to better optimization from the compiler. I have no idea if that is relevant in this use case though. I usually pass pointers, was a bit surprised that both reference and value worked aswell.

Comment: Agree, but in this case `index` is going to be passed as a pointer anyway, so I don't see much room for the optimizer to play.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not compile, `parallel_index.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe1): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.a(thread.o): In function `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)())':
(.text._ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10shared_ptrINS_10_Impl_baseEEPFvvE+0x5f): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @AwaitedOne You are probably missing a compiler/linker flag. On my system with g++ I need to compile/link with `-pthread`.

Comment: Still there is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, that is due to concurrent access as you mentioned above. Have I not used `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx)` in my code to guard the concurrent access.

Comment: @AwaitedOne The segfault is more likely because of `std::thread threads[total_threads-1];` and `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++)` disagreeing on how many elements there are in `threads`, but if you've already fixed that it's probably because `sequence_content.erase(0,erase_length);` changed the size of the sequence while leaving `sequence_length` unchanged. This will allow `seq_itr` to get to dangerous values. Note that moving `sequence_length` into mutex protection will pretty much ruin the point of threading.

Comment: I fixed `std::thread threads[total_threads-1]`, and `sequence_content.erase(0,erase_length)` is not getting executed. It will get executed if `erase_length > 10000`. I think source of segment fault is somethign else.